# photo stream on ubuntu

Tags: installation, apple

Well, I have an iPhone 5, this device (actually, all apples devices) can share pictures, documents and among other things by photo-stream or icloud. I would like to know if having ubuntu I can still use photo-stream, itunes or ic loud.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Only Apple iApp applications like iPhoto can directly access items stored on iCloud. You can access your iCloud files through the iCloud website from any platform/browser.